# Scrape Multiple URLs from CSV using Beautiful Soup & Python

Tags: python, csv, url, beautifulsoup

I'm needing to scrape a list of URLs stored in a CSV file.

I am very new to Beautiful Soup

Comment: Please show us your attempt :)

Comment: You probably won't find an exact solution for *your code*. However, lots of documentation exists for reading a CSV, making HTTP requests, and parsing HTML in python. Focus on that, not the specific ways your code works

Comment: And if you want to say you've searched things, show what isn't working so we won't close your question as possible duplicates of any of them

Comment: You need to learn both: how to make request and how to convert your raw html into soup, then learn how to use beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `urls.csv` file look like:

```
https://stackoverflow.com;code site;
https://steemit.com;block chain social site;
```

The following code will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #required to parse html
import requests #required to make request

#read file
with open('urls.csv','r') as f:
    csv_raw_cont=f.read()

#split by line
split_csv=csv_raw_cont.split('\n')

#remove empty line
split_csv.remove('')

#specify separator
separator=";"

#iterate over each line
for each in split_csv:

    #specify the row index
    url_row_index=0 #in our csv example file the url is the first row so we set 0

    #get the url
    url = each.split(separator)[url_row_index] 

    #fetch content from server
    html=requests.get(url).content

    #soup fetched content
    soup=   BeautifulSoup(html)

    #show title from soup
    print soup.title.string
```

Result:

```
Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers
Steemit
```

More informations: [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: Thanks STEFANI, your example script is exactly what I needed.